# Option to exclude patterns from auto import not working?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

There's this new feature with Typescript 4.8 that allows you to prevent auto import from suggesting files or packages, but I can't seem to make it work.

This is the workspace setting that I have:

```
{
  "typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns": [
    "@stitches/react"
  ]
}
```

But then when I try to import in VS Code it still suggests the library.

I'm sure the settings are being applied because I tested adding another setting in the same file and that setting worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Turns out that VS Code was running Typescript 4.7 internally, which doesn't support the new setting.

I had to set VS Code's Typescript's version to the same one as in my `node_modules` by adding `typescript.tsdk` to my settings:

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
  "typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns": ["@stitches/react"]
}
```