# Get VSCode to ignore folders when auto-inserting import statements

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a typescript project with a hierarchy of files under the `src` folder

```
src
 +-components
 | +-Thing.ts
 | +-Widget.ts
 +-libs
   +-Utils.ts
```

I have typscript setup to generate output in the `dist` folder so I get

```
dist
 +-components
 | +-Thing.d.ts
 | +-Widget.d.ts
 +-libs
   +-Utils.d.ts
```

`dist` is in my `.gitignore`

Often when VSCode auto inserts an `import` statement it's often incorrectly inserting paths to `dist`.

I type

```
  const v: SomeClassInUtils
```

and it inserts

```
import { SomeClassInUtils } from "../../dist/lib/utils"
```

instead of

```
import { SomeClassInUtils } from "../lib/utils"
```

What configuration do I need to set to get VSCode to ignore `dist`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `autoImportFileExcludePatterns` with `dist`:

```json
"typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns": ["dist"]
```

If this doesn't work, try some variations of `dist` like `./dist`, `dist/*`, etc. before commenting.

You can either place this in your user settings (Ctrl + Shift + P > User Settings (JSON)) or create a file `.vscode/settings.json` in the root folder of your project with this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73505801/5172925   need to set the tsdk for vscode